# Linq, should I join those two queries together?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Logins` table which records when user is `login`, `logout` or `loginFailed` and its timestamp. Now I want to get the list of `loginFailed` after last `login` and the `loginFailed` happened within 24 hrs.

What I am doing now is get the last login timestamp first. then use second query to get the final list. do you think I should join those two queries together? Why not? Why yes? And how if yes?

```
var lastLoginTime = (from inRecord in db.Logins
                     where inRecord.Users.UserId == userId
                           && inRecord.Action == "I"
                     orderby inRecord.Timestamp descending
                     select inRecord.Timestamp).Take(1);

if (lastLoginTime.Count() == 1)
{
    DateTime lastInTime = (DateTime)lastLoginTime.First();

    DateTime since = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24);
    String actionStr = "F";    

    var records = from record in db.Logins
                  where record.Users.UserId == userId
                        && record.Timestamp >= since
                        && record.Action == actionStr
                        && record.Timestamp > lastInTime
                  orderby record.Timestamp 
                  select record;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to join the two together? For what purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the long run, I don't think it'd matter. No matter how you actually build the query in LINQ to SQL, the ultimate sequence of events on the DB server will be

1. get lastInTime
2. use lastInTime as part of records filter

Now... doing it as part of a single query will save on roundtrips of the actual date-time, so you can get some performance that way. But I would suggest that you only try to merge them if you absolutely need to because your performance profiling suggested that query was a bottleneck.

Comment: +1 for "only try to merge them if you absolutely need to because your performance profiling suggested that query was a bottleneck."

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you should combine them because your current queries are quite readable. I think if they were combined it would be more difficult to understand the code.

Comment: This is key. I'm a new developer working at a company that has a 'new' version of our software we are going to release. I feel like I spend half my time trying to figure out the code, rather than improving it or finishing the project.

Comment: You can compose more complex queries with the `IQueryable<...>` objects and the `let` keyword to keep the code readable... and possibly even make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. Too many folk are so caught up in "fasted codez possible" these days; readability and maintainability are far more important, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't merge, for reasons already stated by everyone else, but you can simplify the first query a bit: instead of

```
orderby inRecord.Timestamp descending
select inRecord.Timestamp).Take(1);
```

you can simply say:

```
select inRecord.Timestamp).Max();
```

It'll do the same thing, but it's a bit clearer than your way.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the IQueryable objects to compose more complex queries and still keep the code pretty easy to read.  (I mixed the Extension syntax and query syntax just to show it can be done. You can just as easily swap this code around to separate it out as you would any other code in your solution.)

```
var usersRecords = db.Logins.Where(r => r.Users.UserId == userId);

var userLoginTimes = usersRecords.Where(r => r.Action == "I")
                                 .Select(r => r.Timestamp);

var usersFunctions = usersRecords.Where(r => r.Action == "F");

var records = from record in usersFunctions
              where userLoginTimes.Any()
              let lastLoginTime = userLoginTimes.Max()
              where record.Timestamp >= since
                 && record.Timestamp > lastLoginTime
              select record;
```